# How to know the active page is Root page in ionic 4?

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to handle the device back button in ionic 4. But for that i need to know the Active page is root page or not. Previously in ionic 3 there is nav using that we can find which page is root page on the Active index but in ionic 4 how to know that one?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to see   the current page name :

`this.router.url;`

And after that you check if it is the root page.

Comment: Thanks for the help i am getting the current page using this.router.url from that how to check the root page

Comment: You root is always the same. ? Just check if the name is equals to "home" or something like that .

Comment: The pages which i am navigating by SetRoot which doesnot have back button? How to know those pages is root page or not

Comment: Yes ,  the only way I think is to check url name of the route .